# MySQL Bug reference in release notes, but where?

Tags: mysql

This may be a daft question, but on the MySQL release notes, a lot of them are followed by BUG Reference numbers. But most of these BUGS don't exist when you search for them at [bugs.mysql.com](http://bugs.mysql.com).

example: `InnoDB: A full-text query raised an assertion. Under certain circumstances, DDL operations such as ALTER TABLE ... RENAME caused full-text auxiliary tables to be removed on server restart. (`**Bug #13651665**`)`

Despite my best efforts I can't find out where to find these BUGS. Can anyone point me at the right location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those big-numbered bugs are internal to Oracle.  We mere mortals are not allowed to see them.

The visible bugs are numbered under about 82000 (so far), and visible at bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: ok cheers. It seems a bit pointless having them on the public release notes then, but I'm sure they have a good reason. . .

Comment: That is a common grumble.  There are nasty guesses as to the reason.